# Аппаратный firewall, сетевые протоколы

Tags: firewall, сеть

Ожидаю тестового задания, все что знаю о нем, это настройка аппаратного фаервола. но не сталкивался с этим, и не представляю что от меня требуется. Вопрос: что я могу почитать, и как с этим ознакомится, чтобы пройти тестовое задание на практике.

Answer (score 2):

Аппаратных фаерволов не бывает , в любом случае настраивать вы будете софт.  Почитать и ознакомиться вам действительно лучше с сетевыми протоколами, потому что каждый вендер это свой софт, и даже если вы научитесь настраивать на каком нибудь dlink  , вы с ходу не сможете настроить тоже самое на cisco.  А по делу читайте [Таненбаума](https://vk.com/doc101953832_131046287?hash=72cceb87d5e78716a5&dl=28aabb49a7217e1962)

Answer (score 0):

[Dlink DFL-800](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?hid=91088&modelid=1016515&clid=502) называется фаерволом, только из-за WAN порта (встроен программный фаервол, как и в любом другом маршрутизаторе) можешь про него что нибудь почитать.

Answer (score 0):

pyatak, аппаратные фаерволы есть! К примеру cisco asa 5500x. У меня на странице смотри http://vk.com/anonnetworkrus?w=wall180575186_4009 было бы время ещё бы вебинар провёл. Желательно ещё поискать документацию zyxel, cisco и ideco ознакомься с их фаерволами. Тут отдельно про iptables http://vk.com/anonnetworkrus?w=wall180575186_4093 сори что ссылки с vk.

Comment: @pyatak верно ответил. Т.н. аппаратный файерволл - игра слов, ибо имеется ввиду железка (физическое устройство) ни на что не пригодная, кроме выполнения данной специализированной задачи - быть "огненой стеной". Однако все действия по фильтрации пакетов и т.п. выполняет ПО, прошитое в данной железке! И вот из-за того, что ПО вынесли на отдельное устройство и для отличия от софтверных файерволлов, их и прозвали "аппаратными".

Comment: @jack-out Хорошо что времени нет на вебинары, на cisco  стоит cisco IOS , которая как и любой другой программный продукт  имеет интерфейс, версию и т.п. ASA 5505  стоит у меня под рукой, у которой обновленная IOS  на К-9 , для поддержки 3DES. Аппаратный файервол - это что то типа того http://developerslife.ru/2113